# FileInputStream not finding the file

Tags: java, java-io

I am making a program in java that will read a file and put each word from it into an array so I can make an anagram of each word after sorting them to a default array. I have a good idea of how to do this, except my .txt file is not being read. I have a file called "input.txt" in the src with the "anagram.java" program I am writing, but when the code promts for the file entry, upon entering the file name "input.txt" my code says the file does not exist and I get this:

```
Enter file name: 
input.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: input.txt (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
        at anagram.main(anagram.java:23)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Here is the code at the line where is messing up:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter file name: ");
    String fileName = br.readLine();
    File file = new File(fileName);
    if(file.length() == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("File is empty");
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Apparently typing in "input.txt" is not enough information or something, I'm not sure. I removed the

```
    if(file.length() == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("File is empty");
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

To get the error I stated above, which is how I figured out it wasn't even recognizing the file in the src with the anagram.java prgm.

What is wrong with my code? Why is it not reading the file or saying it isn't there?

Comment: You do not have to specify JAVA in title when you have the tag for it.

Comment: You have to provide the full path to a file.  In Windows, that would be C:\directory\subdirectory\input.txt

Comment: Have you tried to specify the full path? If you start you program from *bin* it does not know where to look for the file.

Comment: The code you have posted does not throw that exception. Have another look at the stack trace.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc No, you don't have to provide the full path, but if you don't, the name has to be relative to the current working directory.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I dare say the file is in the `src` directory - but I suspect that's *not* the current working directory of the program. To check this, run this code:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

Options:

- Specify an absolute filename
- Specify a relative filename which takes into account where you're running this
- Bundle the file as a resource and use `Class.getResourceAsStream` or similar

Note that this has nothing to do with `BufferedReader` - you're reading the text from `System.in` with no problems.

Comment: Excellent! Indeed it was not reading from the src file. I am reading the file now, but I am getting a complex output of brackets and slashes that look like some formatting code. The file was originally and .rtf, but when I changed it to a .txt I noticed this when I looked at the info of the file with the dropmenu selection "get info" I will revert it to rtf and see what happens...

Comment: @RyanTibbetts: It's not clear what you mean by "changed it to a .txt" - renaming the file won't change its context. It sounds like you are indeed seeing RTF...

Comment: I reverted it to an .rtf and although the info tab shows it as normal, it would appear the program is still reading it literally.

Comment: @RyanTibbetts: Well yes, it would. You're asking it to just read the text of the file - and the text of the file *is* the RTF stuff. It sounds like you need code which understands RTF - or change your source data. Either way, that's a matter for a separate question.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for your help Jon.

Answer (score 1):

It's looking in a path different than your source directory. Try specifying a full path like `c:\input.txt` (but don't forget to move your file there!) to see what I mean.