# Unable to read a file from a jar into a FileInputStream using a relative path

Tags: java, properties, relative-path, fileinputstream

Given I am able to load my *mail.properties* file such as :

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("META-INF.mail");
System.out.prinltn("subject :" + rb.getString("email.subject")); //output : 'subject : Job Application'
```

However I am unable to read; in the same method; my *mail.properties* file as a `FileInputStream`. I have tried all these options none of them worked and I am always getting a `FileNotFoundException` :

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("META-INF/mail.properties");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("META-INF//mail.properties");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("META-INF\\mail.properties");
```

The folder *META-INF* exists within a jar that is loaded at build time :

[image]

Any help will be more than appreciated.

Comment: can you share your directory structure. Where is `Meta-INF` directory exactly?

Comment: Also share the output of `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());` Put this line before the line that is throwing exception.

Comment: @catchingUp : I have added the directory structure as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `FileInputStream()` will look for paths relative to current directory. Since your `META-INF` is inside the imported jar, it won't be able to find it.

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15368111/2458858), you have following options:

1. Specify an absolute filename
2. Specify a relative filename which takes into account where you're running this
3. Bundle the file as a resource and use `Class.getResourceAsStream` or similar

check it out for more details.
My question if you are able to load it with `ResourceBundle`, why are you trying to reload it in a different way?

Comment: Thanks for your feed-back. To answer your question : It is related to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366941/unable-to-read-the-last-duplicate-key-of-a-properties-file
I would like to make sure I am reading the right mail.properties file. To do that I want to print the whole mail.properties file into the console or copy/paste it in some other folder.

Comment: Then try with the absolute file path. To get absolute path inside jar, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14612564/2458858